Does anyone have a source that refers to Gödel and Kant with respect to the incompleteness theorems? (In simple language for physicists)
I am looking for an easy-to-understand paper written for people who are not experts in philosophy. It should explicitly address Gödel's incompleteness theorems and explain why they do not refute Kant's critical idealism. The reason is that I have repeatedly encountered physicists who assume they do. However, I haven't found papers that are simple enough for them to understand. Can anyone help me?

I can't think of any way that Godel would have refuted Kant. It is widely held that the discovery of non-Euclidean geometry refuted Kant, though. Could you be mis-remembering something you read?

@David Of course he didn't, that's true, but I would like to have an essay for physicists who are not familiar with Kant and interpret the sentences incorrectly.

"why Gödel did not prove that Kant's philosophy was not refuted by."? Can you please change that question - as formulated it's not grammatically correct and I've no idea what you're asking. Also -- as @DavidGudeman commented -- Gödel did not try to prove or disprove anything about Kant's philosophy.

I mean, Gödel had his own ontological proof of Gods existence, while Kant argued that an ontological proof was impossible. This seems not very interesting to physicists, but perhaps that is what you are referring to?

I am concerned that physicists often try to argue against Kant using Gödel, which indicates a misunderstanding. However, it’s difficult to point out their mistake because they lack sufficient knowledge on the subject. I’m now looking for a straightforward paper that I can show them—something not written for experts, but for people who are not deeply familiar with philosophy. I will then revise my question accordingly.

I am referring to the incompleteness theorems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems

Fine, but which physicists are you talking about?

mudskipper Theoretical physicists who are not deeply familiar with philosophy. Basically, it doesn't matter—just a work for people who are not experts in this field.
Mauro Thanks for it, i will have a look on it! :))

I think the issue we are having is that no one here seems to know how physicists argue against Kant using Godel. I've never heard of such a thing, and I doubt there are any papers on it. Maybe if you could outline the argument that these physicists use we could recommend something to address those specific issues.

David They claim that philosophy is irrelevant to physics because Gödel supposedly showed that all "systems" cannot be consistently closed. They confuse systems based on axioms with philosophical systems that operate with philosophical principles, which are not axioms. This misunderstanding arises because they fail to clearly distinguish between philosophy, logic, and mathematics. They lack a fundamental understanding of what a priori knowledge is and what an axiom is. Or what pure reason is, etc.
